# How does module_enable works in Drush?

Tags: drush

I'm trying to automatize an install of CiviCRM and Drupal, but I'm getting so many errors! (Using PHP 7, Drush 8, Drupal 7, CiviCRM 4.7.18)

CiviCRM has a Drush extension, which calls function `module_enable(array('civicrm'))`

However, Drush 8 (which says is compatible with D6, D7 and D8) throws `Undefined function`.

I would like to know if I should downgrade my Drush 8 or what?
Can I fix this error in some way?

These are the errors I get.

```
Error: Call to undefined function module_enable() in drush_civicrm_install() (line 367 of /root/.drush/civicrm.drush.inc) #0               [error]
phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(422): drush_civicrm_install()
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc(458): drush_main()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc(365): drush_run_main(false, '/', 'Phar detected. ...')
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/drush(114): drush_startup(Array)
#8 /usr/local/bin/drush(10): require('phar:///usr/loc...')
#9 {main}.
Error: Call to undefined function module_enable() in /root/.drush/civicrm.drush.inc on line 367 #0 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(422): drush_civicrm_install()
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc(458): drush_main()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc(365): drush_run_main(false, '/', 'Phar detected. ...')
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/drush(114): drush_startup(Array)
#8 /usr/local/bin/drush(10): require('phar:///usr/loc...')
#9 {main}
Error: Call to undefined function module_enable() in drush_civicrm_install() (line 367 of /root/.drush/civicrm.drush.inc).
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
```

Changing it to `drush_module_enable()` ends in another error:

```
Drupal\Core\Extension\MissingDependencyException: Unable to install modules civicrm due to missing modules civicrm. in                     [error]
/opt/compucorp/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php:85
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/compucorp/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(83): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array,
true)
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment.inc(131): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array,
true)
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment.inc(198): drush_module_install(Array)
#3 /root/.drush/civicrm.drush.inc(367): drush_module_enable(Array)
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(422): drush_civicrm_install()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command()
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc(458): drush_main()
#10 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc(365): drush_run_main(false, '/', 'Phar detected. ...')
#11 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/drush(114): drush_startup(Array)
#12 /usr/local/bin/drush(10): require('phar:///usr/loc...')
#13 {main}
```

Comment: This by using `drush dl drupal-7` (instead of just `drupal`), since CiviCRM is not ready for Drupal 8 yet.
**Credits**: [JorgeeFG](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/50363/jorgeefg), as per [this comment](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/posts/18292/timeline#comment_20386) to an answer in a cross posted question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code is raising an exception like Drupal\Core\Extension\MissingDependencyException, you aren't using Drupal 7, but Drupal 8, which doesn't have a `module_enable()` function anymore.

You don't need to down-grade Drupal, but use the correct Drupal version, which in your case (since the CiviCRM Drush extension is calling `module_enable()`) is Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

`module_enable` is a Drupal 7 function - it would seem you're not running this command on a drupal 7 site.

Downgrading Drush won't have any effect, if you want to use this extension with Drupal 8 the code will need to be updated to satisfy the new API.

The new equivalent is:

```
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->enable(['civicrm']);
```